# Update datagrid row that is in edit state to source from code

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol, datarowview

I have a Datagrid with `SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"` set.

With my DataGrid being in the content area of a TabControl, the currently edited row is being discarded when I switch the tab.

I figured when I get the `DataRowView` of the current row, I can call `row?.EndEdit();` (which is being triggered by a enter hit on the keyboard, but can also be called manually) to update the data to source. However, I cant seem to get the current `DatarRowView`.

How could I tell the DataGrid to update all the currently edited data to source? Is my approach the correct one, and if yes, how do I get the current `DataRowView`?

If not, how do I tell the DataGrid to finish edit mode and update its new data to source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a straight solution, however will solve the problem.

One can simply focus another control on the gui, and the `DataGrid` will commit its changes to the current row. The effect is the same as if you press enter while you edit the `DataGrid`.

Example:

I have a `TabControl`. When the TabControl switches the tab, I want the current changes saved.

The xaml of the TabControl:

```
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                x:Name="TabControl" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabContentTemplateSelector}"
                SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
....
```

Note the `SelectionChanged="TabControl_OnSelectionChanged"` but it can be any other event on any other control you want. Even a command, whatever.

What you then want, is simply focus another gui element:

```
private void TabControl_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // focus the tab control to lose focus on datagrids - they will then commit changes if possible.
  TabControl.Focus(); // my TabControl is x:Name="TabControl", Focus sets the focus
}
```

As mentioned, the effect is exactly the same as if you press enter while editing the cell.

Comment: I tested this, but it is NOT so. The datagrid stays in edit mode.

Comment: Hmm. It worked for what I needed. What do you mean with stays in edit mode? The question was about forcing it to update to source, not exiting edit mode. You can call `Cell.EndEdit()` if you wanna exit the edit mode.

Comment: Maybe my issue is a bit different. I have a tab control with some datagrids in there, and when I switch tabs, I want the data grid I am currently editing to commit its changes. Simply using `tabControl.Focus()` did not do the trick for me, I explicitly had to commit the changes of the respective datagrids.

Comment: @rabejens Interesting. Maybe it has to do with different binding and focus settings, but glad it worked for you in the end.